# python gettext fails to translate EDX project

Tags: python, django, translation, gettext, edx

I am working on open EDX project which is built by `django 1.8`. Currently i am working on localization and I'm translating it to a new language. Both the Source and target languages are Unicode encoded.
Altough i have translated, `gettext` fails to load some expressions. By that i mean in `PO` file i provided the correct translation but for example the original phrase is loaded in the menu.

This is the mentioned line:

```
<a href="${certificates_url}">${_("Certificates")}</a>
```

In the file:

[header.html](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/open-release/eucalyptus.master/cms/templates/widgets/header.html#L101)

In that example `Certificates` is shown instead of its translation.

Any idea why it happens ? And how to track this issue.

Answer (score 0):

check `django.po` file and check if there is a fuzzy flag on top of its translation.
It may have happened by translator's decision for a later review or because of a conflict during merging some base files translation.

Solve conflicts and make sure about the translation then simply remove fuzzy flag and recompile `django.po`.

[More info on this issue](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/gettext_9.html#Fuzzy-Entries)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks so much. You're a life saver :)